# Show custom page for not found url

Tags: nginx

I want to show certain pages for my url

For example when visiting below link

```
https://www.example.com/blog/unlock-subconscious-mind-power/
```

must show content of rewrite/blog.php

But I am getting not found URL.

I tried below code

```
fastcgi_read_timeout 3200;
fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    location /blog {
        try_files $uri $uri/ $uri/index.php @rewrites;
    }

    location @rewrites {
        rewrite ^([^.]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;
        rewrite ^ /rewrite/blog.php last;
    }
```

Its still giving 404 error.

Comment: Does `https://www.example.com/rewrite/blog.php` work? Or does it generate a 404?

Comment: It is working fine , I even tried full path like /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/rewrite/blog.php